# ResponseBuilder - Long cannot be cast to Collection?

Tags: java, rest, classcastexception

I have this: 
`Map<String, Object> social = new HashMap<String, Object>(); social.put("socialId", socialId);
social.put("savedComment", savedComment);`

and I'm trying to do this: `builder = Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(social);`

Why am I receiving HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Collection, since Object should work with Long and general Object classes? Can't I send two different types of data, so data contains data.socialId (as a Long) and data.savedComment (as an object)?

*By the way, socialId is a Long object, and savedComment is a SocialComment object.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the API docs for `entity()`, it says

> Any Java type instance for a response entity, that is supported by
>   the runtime can be passed. It is the callers responsibility to wrap
>   the actual entity with GenericEntity if preservation of its generic
>   type is required.

So your map needs to support `GenericEntity` if you need to preserve it's type in the response.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#entity-java.lang.Object-

Comment: How could I wrap it with GenericEntity?